# What's the best option for a virtual keyboard component in a Java web application?

Tags: java, security, jsf, servlets, applet

I would like to know what kind of technology would be better to create a virtual keyboard component, that needs to be installed in different web applications.

All these application are Java, but some use Struts, other uses JSF.

A Java applet + servlet would be the best choice concerning security?

My idea is to write an applet + servlet.
All applications would need to add the servlet/mapping in their "web.xml" file.
The applet would communicate with the servlet passing information.

The fact of signing an applet with a certificate make it secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java applets is generally a bad idea for the last 12 years. Javascript and HTML 5 provide you enough functionality to create any UI you want. Java applet requires JVM installed and configured on client side.

Signing applet does not add anything to its security. It means that the applet is can perform operations that forbidden to unsigned applets. It means that additionally to installation of java use must give your applet permission to run.

As I understand you want virtual keyboard. So, type "javascript virtual keyboard" in google and get a lot of ready-to-use lightweight components that do not require any download and work in most existing browsers. For example take a look on this implementation: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsvk/

Comment: Hi @AlexR. Thanks for your response. I have a doubt. If the keyboard has some security requirements, like for example, the keys are ramdomized for every user session. Is this ok to do via javascript? Is javascript secure? I'm not sure but I think javascript can be dynamically changed by the browser.